# Product of compact metric spaces is again compact.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

**Proof**
Let $(X_j,d_j)$ be a compact metric space for $j=1,...,n$. Denote $X=X_1 \times X_2 \times...\times X_n$ to be the product of compact metric spaces.

Assume the property that the open sets in $(X,d)$ are unions of product sets of the form $U_1 \times ... \times U_n$, where $U_j$ is an open subset of $X_j$.

Suppose $X\subset \bigcup_{\alpha\in A} U^{\alpha}$, where $U^{\alpha}=U_1^{\alpha}\times ... \times U_n^{\alpha}$, and $U_j^{\alpha}\subset X_j$ are open.

Now, we have that $X_j\subset \bigcup_{\alpha\in A} U_j^{\alpha}$, for if $x_j\in X_j$, $\exists y\in X$ such that $y_j=x_j$, but $y\in U^{\alpha}=U_1^{\alpha}\times ... \times U_n^{\alpha}$ for some $\alpha$.

$\implies y_j=x_j\in U_j^{\alpha}$.

So by compactness of $X_j$, $\exists$ a finite subcover $X_j\subset \bigcup^{m(j)}_{i=1} U_j^i$, where $X_j$ is covered by $m(j)$ open sets for each $j=1,...,n$.

Finally, $X\subset \bigcup_{1\leq i_j\leq m(j)} (U_1^{i_1} \times U_2^{i_2} \times ...\times U_n^{i_n})$ is a union of $\Pi^n_{i=1}m(i)<\infty$ open subsets of $X$, hence $X$ is compact.
**end Proof**

Is this a valid way of arguing? My main concern is that the open cover at the end of the proof is not actually a subcover... or that it contains a subcover plus some surplus open sets.

Comment: The textbook I am using assumes this part.

Comment: I am sorry. I misread.

Comment: You can work with two spaces $X$ and $Y$. Then the rest is induction. Now, $X\times Y\subset \bigcup_\alpha (U_\alpha\times V_\alpha)$ and you infer correctly that $X\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^nU_{\alpha_i}$ and $Y\subset\bigcup_{j=1}^mU_{\alpha_j}$. Then $X\times Y\subset$ ???

Comment: But how do we know that $U_{\alpha_i} \times V_{\alpha_j}=U_{\alpha} \times V_{\alpha}$ for any $\alpha$?

Comment: My answer in the case of two sets would be $X \times Y \subset \bigcup_{1\leq i\leq n, 1\leq j \leq m} U_{\alpha_i} \times V_{\alpha_j}$

Comment: Exactly! I find it nicer to write $X\times Y\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n\bigcup_{j=1}^m(U_{\alpha_i}\times V_{\alpha_j})$.

Comment: I guess what I was afraid of originally was that the sets $U_{\alpha_1},...,U_{\alpha_n}$ which cover $X$ do not always coincide with the $V_{\alpha_1},...,V_{\alpha_m}$ which cover $Y$. Is it possible that none of the $mn$ different combinations are actually within $\bigcup_{\alpha}(U_\alpha \times V_{\alpha})$?

Comment: Uh, oh, you're right. So, we don't have a subcover. Hmm, lemme think...

Comment: Sorry. Can't think anymore. Too tired. Good night...

Comment: Good night and thank you for your comments ^^

Comment: You cannot assume that the open sets in $(X,d)$ are of the form $U_1\times...\times U_n.$ Sets  of this form make a base (basis) for $(X,d).$ However it is sufficient to show that any cover of $X$ by sets of this form has a finite sub-cover. Because if a space has a base B such that any cover by members of B has a finite sub-cover  then the space is compact.

Answer (score 2):

We are starting out with a cover of the form $U^\alpha_1 \times \ldots U^\alpha_n$, where the $\alpha \in A$ vary. These are *specific* combinations of open sets in the factor spaces that are combined to form basic open sets of the product.

If you then **independently** (as you do) take a subcover $U_i^\alpha$ for $X_i$, $\alpha$ from some finite subset $F_i\subseteq A$ of indices, there is no guarantee at all that the sets you got from the finite subcover combine to the original products that you started with. It *is* true that

$$\{U^{\alpha_1}_1 \times \ldots \times U_n^{\alpha_n}: \forall i: \alpha_i \in F_i\}$$

is a finite *cover* of the product, it is not a *subcover* of the original one.

You can use the tube lemma (or variations thereof) to show that the product of two compact (not necessarily metric, general spaces will do..) spaces is compact and the finite product case then follows by standard finite induction. The infinite product case does require new techniques.